# How to change uploadaheadsize on iis 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a application developed in asp net mvc 4  (IIS 7 and windows server 2008) and it has a upload system.

The problem is that with large files I get an 413 http error.

I am trying to set uploadaheadsize but can´t find it anywhere.

Tried Roles and features and also in application pool. Could someone guide me through this config setting?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Just added:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

in my web.config!

**Edit 1:**

In addition, I found this useful information on www.iis.net:

> The requestLimits element specifies limits on HTTP requests that are
>   processed by the Web server. These limits include the maximum size of
>   a request, the maximum URL length, and the maximum length for a query
>   string. In addition, the  element can contain a
>   collection of user-defined HTTP header limits in the 
>   element, which allows you to define custom settings on HTTP headers.

reference: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits